# AWS device-farm iOS XCTest UI suite can't access main app's container

Tags: ios, xctest, aws-device-farm

I'm using XCTestUI to write automated tests for an iOS app.
Got a couple of tests running on Xcode Simulator and on several real devices (iPhones).
When I try to run the exact same tests in AWS device-farm, on the same devices (including iOS versions), all tests are failing with error:

> `container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier`

Now, I double checked that both bundles  are in the same appGroup `group.com.company.appName` and everything looks in order.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am an engineer on the AWS Device Farm team. Do you mind providing me with a run url so I can take a look at your test execution? Just from the description, this seems like an entitlement issue when your application is resigned to be compatible with our iOS devices.

For better assistance, I suggest utilizing the AWS Device Farm forums as a medium to contact members of the the service team like myself: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193

Andy

Comment: thanks for reaching out to me!
here's a run URL that you can take a look at: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?#/projects/d09eebe5-eb15-4ac3-a554-3af02e38d19f/runs/f5b23ead-09a0-406f-8f2e-978eedd5fbde

there's also a forum post on forum.aws.amazon.com regarding my problem: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=983174#983174